# MVC5: The view rendered out unexpected codes 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1...' at top of HTML. Anyone know what happen?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to MVC5. I wanted to display a list of collection in the view which I did. But there is an unexpected coding (System.Collections.Generic.List`1...) appears at the top of the HTML when the view is rendered.

[Please view the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCMTk.jpg)

Seems like it render @Model IEnumerable<CompanyManagementSystem.ViewModels.UserViewModel> I declared at the top of the view. How do I get rid of it?

Here is the source code :)

```
@Model IEnumerable<CompanyManagementSystem.ViewModels.UserViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Management";
}

@section Link {
    <link href="~/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}

<h1 class="h3 mb-2 text-gray-500">@ViewBag.Title</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card shadow mb-4">
            <div class="card-header py-3">
                <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Users Listing</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">

                @Html.ActionLink("Add New User", "New", "UserManagement", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

                <br />
                <br />

                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="users" class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Mobile Number</th>
                                <th>Position</th>
                                <th>Active User</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach(var user in Model)
                            {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-icon-split" href="@Url.Action("Edit", "UserManagement", new { Id = user.Id})">
                                        <span class='icon text-white-50'>
                                            <i class='fas fa-edit'></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class='text'>Edit</span>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `model` with a lowercase m.

Wrong:

```
@Model IEnumerable<CompanyManagementSystem.ViewModels.UserViewModel>
```

Correct:

```
@model IEnumerable<CompanyManagementSystem.ViewModels.UserViewModel>
```

The version with lowercase m is used to specify the type of the model of the view. The version with uppercase M actually accesses the concrete model instance of the view at runtime.

Comment: Ah... I see. Good observation, NineBerry!